# How to use ndb.OR in a loop?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The correct way of using an ndb.OR is like this:

```
q = News.query(ndb.OR(News.source == 'GRD', News.source == 'IND'))
```

Which results in an OR-filter.

> Query(kind='News', filters=OR(FilterNode('source', '=', 'GRD'),
>   FilterNode('source', '=', 'IND')))

But how do I do that in a loop?

When I try this:

```
q = News.query()
for source in sources:
    q = q.filter(ndb.OR(News.source == source))
```

It becomes an AND-filter:

> Query(kind='News', filters=AND(FilterNode('source', '=', 'GRD'),
>   FilterNode('source', '=', 'IND')))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you repeatedly apply filters like that, you are chaining the filters, with each filter filtering the already filtered results.

To filter by any of your `sources` you can use `IN`.  Quoting from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in):

> Similarly, the IN operation

```
property IN [value1, value2, ...]
```

> which tests for membership in a list of possible values, is implemented as

```
(property == value1) OR (property == value2) OR ...
```

So you could do:

```
qry = News.query(News.source.IN(sources))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant `q = News.query(ndb.OR(News.source.IN(sources)))`

Comment: @Houman `IN` is actually implemented as a series of `OR`s (see quote above!).

Comment: Becareful as there is a limit on the number of elements for `IN` operator